# How to speed up SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

My MariaDB slow query log shows a lot of the below.

```
Time: 221202 11:46:57
Query_time: 5.022055  Lock_time: 0.000082  Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 447119
Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 141
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  ab_posts.ID
                    FROM ab_posts  LEFT JOIN ab_postmeta ON ( ab_posts.ID = ab_postmeta.post_id AND ab_postmeta.meta_key = 'cid' )  LEFT JOIN ab_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( ab_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
                    WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ab_postmeta.post_id IS NULL 
  AND 
  mt1.meta_key = '_json_file'
) AND ab_posts.post_type = 'listings' AND ((ab_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
                    GROUP BY ab_posts.ID
                    ORDER BY ab_posts.post_date DESC
                    LIMIT 0, 5;
```

How can I speed up the query? Should I create any index to speed things up?

UPDATE: Below is the `EXPLAIN` query and indices of the two tables - ab_post_meta and ab_posts

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: And I think I found the source. The query is generated by WordPress core file `wp-includes\class-wp-query.php`

```
    $found_rows = '';
    if ( ! $q['no_found_rows'] && ! empty( $limits ) ) {
        $found_rows = 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS';
    }

    $old_request = "
        SELECT $found_rows $distinct $fields
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} $join
        WHERE 1=1 $where
        $groupby
        $orderby
        $limits
    ";
```

Comment: Is the query quick without sql_calc_found_rows?

Comment: @Shadow No. It is as slow. I just did a test query remotely. Should I create any index to speed things up?

Comment: You should 1) run an explain on your query and share the results with us. You should also share what indexes you have on the underlying tables.

Comment: @Shadow I just added the explain query results and indices. Appreciate it if you can look at it as I'm a noob in SQL

Comment: Why is the `explain` key_len column not showing a key length? What does the text version show? (always prefered over images). Same with `show create table {tablename}` instead o the image, as you can see you cannot identify index names or orders.  Btw, which MariaDB version?

Comment: I'm not sure why. I ran HeidiSQL client to query it. Text ver shows the same thing. The image is from Excel showing the CSV file. I'm running MariaDB 10.4.

Comment: Add the plugin: [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the culprit. The answer is explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288710/how-to-speed-up-wp-query-took-more-5s-to-run-against-100k-posts).

I do have a meta_query as below.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => MAX_LIMIT,  
    'post_type' => listings',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc',  
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'cid',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_json_file',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
    ));
```